# SQL Server - access to sys.views for a highly privileged user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have case where I want a database user to have db_owner privileges with regard to one databases on the server, but be able to see absolutely nothing of other databases on the server, including, for example, the sys.databases view.  I have tried denying select on this view at the master database level, but this prevents the user even from connecting to the one database that they own.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DENY VIEW ANY DATABASES`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077.aspx